# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable?

Tags: python

Here's a program I wrote for calculating the sum of all multiples of 3 and 5 less than n:

```
n=int(input)
a=n//3
b=n//5
c=n//15
d=a(a-1)
e=b(b-1)*2
f=c(c-1)*7
print(d+e-f)
```

I'm receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Solution.py", line 12, in <module>

    d=a(a-1)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Please help me fix the program

Comment: what do you thing this here is doing: "a(a-1)" ????

Comment: `d=a(a-1)` should be `d=a*(a-1)`.. so on and so forth.. use `*` for every multiplication. this is python - not math

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I was trying to multiply the two terms; thanks a lot for your explanation, I see my mistake now

Answer (score 0):

when you do:

```
d=a(a-1)
```

then it looks like d is assigned with the value returned from calling a function name `a`, taking as parameter `a-1` which is making no sense for a since a is actually an integer...

you mean for sure something like

```
d = a*(a-1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I see where I went wrong now